# HC-SR04 with STM32 gives unexpected values

Tags: sensor, stm32, stm32f103c8t6, hal, hc-sr04

On an Arduino it is easy to get an HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor getting to work.
However, on my STM32(F103C8T6) I get strange values.

I assumed I connect it correctly, since I get values on the trigger pin.
I checked the voltage on the 5V pin going to VCC of the HC-SR04 is 4.87 V.

The following program I used (only most important parts and with generated comments removed):

```
// PA10 US1 Trigger
#define US1_Trigger_Port GPIOA
#define US1_Trigger_Pin  GPIO_PIN_10
// PA9 US1 Echo
#define US1_Echo_Port GPIOA
#define US1_Echo_Pin  GPIO_PIN_9

uint32_t us1_duration;
uint32_t us1_distance;

uint32_t raw_values[1024];
uint32_t n = 0;
```

And for the loop (default part, auto generated by CubeMX):

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_NVIC_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(US1_Trigger_Port, US1_Trigger_Pin, SET);
    HAL_Delay(10);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(US1_Trigger_Port, US1_Trigger_Pin, RESET);

    uint8_t state;
    do
    {
      state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(US1_Echo_Port, US1_Echo_Pin);
    } while (state == RESET);
    uint32_t us1_start = HAL_GetTick();

    do
    {
      state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(US1_Echo_Port, US1_Echo_Pin);
    } while (state == SET);

    uint32_t us1_end = HAL_GetTick();
    us1_duration = us1_end - us1_start;

    us1_distance = (us1_duration / 2) / 29.1; // cm (?)
    raw_values[n] = us1_duration;

    n++;
    if (n == 1024)
    {
      break;
    }

    HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the break statement to stop the program to check values. I moved my hand between 10 and 20 cm (4-8 inches) away from the sensor but the raw values I get are:

```
Name : raw_values
Details:{195, 196, 1, 1, 196, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 197, 0 <repeats 1013 times>}
Default:0x20001070 <raw_values>
Decimal:536875120
Hex:0x20001070
Binary:100000000000000001000001110000
Octal:04000010160
```

The raw values I expect would be in 10-20cm range (at least most of them), which would result according to the datasheet in raw values of 10 * 58 to 20 * 58 which is 580 to 1060. Especially not around 0's and not all same values around a certain value (this time 200).

The data sheet info I used can be found here: [datasheet](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf)

**Update**
I checked it with a logic analyzer, and noticed the high parts of the echo durations are less than 1 ms. I don't know why I still get values of 200 sometimes, maybe when there is no echo.

Comment: what raw values are you expecting?

Comment: @jsotola I updated my question ... I would expect values to be in 580-1060 range.

Comment: This is what counters are for.  Your interrupts should be starting and stopping counters.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I was hoping to manually start a timer (since I only need it for measuring time). I'm reading some more documentation :-)

Comment: You're measuring very short times, and you're trying for accuracy.  It's hard to know your needs, but polling for a change is often wrong for this type of thing.  A timer hooked by interrupts to your echo pulse is dead simple, and the most accurate you can get.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I just made a new question about how to start a timer, but I probably need to trigger it from that ... actually, to end it. About dead simple, I just have a few months (spare free time) experience with STM32, so dead simple is relative :-)

Comment: @ScottSeidman Still I would have the same question: how to start the time manually? I should stop it when the echo pulse has been received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the HAL_getTick returns milliseconds, and the echos are less than 1 ms (sometimes).

However, I changed it just by counting the loop iterations and I get much better values:

```
Name : raw_values
    Details:{118, 233, 797, 971, 268, 15, 290, 854, 455, 62, 258, 525, 867, 865, 866, 581, 576, 576, 587, 588, 581, 0 <repeats 1003 times>}
```

The last 8 values (except the 0) I got when I placed a box steadily in front of the sensor.

I think if I calculate the exact duration (in ms) of one loop it should be ok and I forget about the bad resolution of the HAL ticks. Or I should use some hardware timer that I start and check.